# face detection using opencv not working

Tags: java, c++, linux, opencv

I am trying to create a sample face detection application using OpenCv library. 
I followed the following tutorials

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers

But Iam getting the following warning and it is not detecting faces.

```
Hello, OpenCV

Running DetectFaceDemo
Detected 0 faces
Writing faceDetection.png
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
```

Please help me.I am using linuxMint+eclipse system.

Comment: your image was not read properly (so it could not detect anything).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is with the

```
FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath()
```

It returns something like this

```
/C:/src/open/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
```

The slash at the begining should be removed

```
FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1)
```

Comment: you are correct. the issue was with resources loading from classpath. I addressed them in absolute path. It worked fine, thanks.

Comment: @Valath, I got the same error after the slash issue in the path fixed with substring(1).

Comment: What is the result of this? *FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath()*

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CascadeClassifier faceDetector=newCascadeClassifier(JavaCam.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1));
```